# Play store shows 0 supported device out ot 15000+ devices

Tags: android, google-play

We have issue with Google play store, My app shows 0 supported device, We have checked it on different devices it's working fine on all devices, But on google play store it is showing,"your device is not compatible with this version." and on Control Panel Shows 0 Supported Device, Anyone can help me??
 my mainfest is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.studybox">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20"
        android:maxSdkVersion="24"/>

    <application
        android:name="com.studybox.Controller.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!-- Google GCM -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <!-- Google MAP API key -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="xxxx" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.studybox.Splash"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.studybox.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.studybox.Login"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.studybox.ForgetPassword"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.studybox.Register"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.studybox.DashBoard"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.studybox.StartNow"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.studybox.InstituteDetail"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.studybox.StudyMaterial"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.studybox.BookInstitute"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.studybox.Notifications"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.studybox.MockTest"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_mock_test"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.studybox.StartMockTest"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.studybox.MyCourse"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.studybox.RoomDiscussion"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.studybox.DiscussionQueries"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.studybox.QueryDetails"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.studybox.MyCourseList"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.studybox.PrivacyPolicy"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.studybox.CourseDetails_"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.studybox.CourseInstitutes"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.studybox.Reviews"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.studybox.CourseRequets"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.studybox.MockTextResult"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.studybox.BatchList"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.studybox.SeeReviews"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.studybox.ClassSchedule"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.studybox.NotificationMessageActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.paytm.pgsdk.PaytmPGActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <service android:name="com.studybox.Notification.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
Any one can help me:
```

Gradle:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.studybox"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 20
        maxSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes
            {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies
        {
            compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
            androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
                exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
            })
            compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
            testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
            compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
            compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
            compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
            compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
            compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
            compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
            compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
            compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
            compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
            compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
            compile 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.4@aar'
            compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
            compile files('libs/PGSDK_V2.0.jar')
        }
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

App Has PayTm integration.

Comment: I'd open the apk in the Apk analyzer tool in Android Studio and look at the merged AndroidManifest file. Maybe there's some weird version conflict which cannot be intercepted while building your apk with gradle.

Comment: Sorry but we can't provide you apk, kindly review code and provide me your suggetion.

Comment: Ok, you misunderstood me. I said what I'd do if I were you. By that I mean: YOU should try that with your `apk` file. I don't want your apk.

Comment: Ok i have tried it also working fine.

Comment: I think you still don't understand me... Did you analyze the merged manifest in your apk?

Comment: i analyze apk and find below mainfest

Comment: in which xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" is red

Comment: Can you help me to resolve it there are more diffrences in mainfest of Debug and release apk.

Comment: @Suneel what Bartek Lipinski saying is that you should check whole merged manifest file. and the red line in merged manifest should not be the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your support buddy...

Answer (score 0):

```
'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
```

Dependency has problem, I have changed it from

```
 'compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
```

Now problem have solved.